# MariaDB Wrong Query result

Tags: null, mariadb

I've a strange problem with a Query on MariaDB.

```
WITH mt AS (SELECT id, MAX(id), employee_id FROM hirings group BY employee_id)
                   SELECT d.*, mt.employee_id, mt.id FROM mt
                   LEFT JOIN hirings a ON a.id = mt.id
                   LEFT JOIN employees d ON d.id = mt.employee_id
                   WHERE (dischargedate IS NULL OR dischargedate > CURDATE()-1) AND company_id = 1
                   GROUP BY d.id ORDER BY surname
```

The query select all employees that have dischargedate valorized to NULL or dischargedate valorized with a value greater then today's date.

Until recently this query works fine, now it have started to doesn't select some records that should be selected.

But in some PC happens this and in other PC whith same DB and same query all works fine.

All PC's have Windows 10 Professional and the MariaDB version is the same.

I extracted manually (with a query) the record of employees and hirings table for comparation with the 2 databases.
The record extraced are identical and I can't find a explanation for this issue.

**Example:**
*--> This record does not appear in the query result:*

Query: **SELECT * FROM employees WHERE surname=’DOE’**

Result: **employees (1r x 35)**

```
------------------------------------
| id | Surname | Name | Address | …
|----|---------|------|---------|---
| 413|   DOE   | JOHN | xxx     | …
|----|---------|------|---------|---
```

Query: **SELECT * FROM hirings WHERE employee_id = 413**

Result: **hirings (5r x 11)**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | Employee_id | WeekHour | Level_id | Contract_id | DeadlineType | DeadlineDate | PartTime | ChargeDate | DischargeDate | Contract |
|----|-------------|----------|----------|-------------|--------------|--------------|----------|------------|---------------|----------|
| 493|     413     |   40     |     4    |      4      |        1     | 2022-01-31   |    0     | 2021-12-20 | 2022-01-31    |  (NULL)  |
| 545|     413     |   40     |     4    |      4      |        1     | 2022-04-30   |    0     | 2022-02-01 | 2022-04-30    |  (NULL)  |
| 618|     413     |   40     |     4    |      4      |        1     | 2022-06-30   |    0     | 2022-05-01 | 2022-06-30    |  (NULL)  |
| 661|     413     |   40     |     4    |      2      |        4     | 2022-12-31   |    0     | 2022-07-01 | 2022-10-07    |  (NULL)  |
| 746|     413     |   40     |     4    |      1      |        1     | (NULL)       |    0     | 2022-10-10 | (NULL)        |  (NULL)  |
|----|-------------|----------|----------|-------------|--------------|--------------|----------|------------|---------------|----------|
```

*--> This record appear in the query result:*
Query: **SELECT * FROM employees WHERE surname=’STOJ’**

Result: **employees (1r x 35)**

```
------------------------------------
| id | Surname | Name | Address | …
------------------------------------
| 469|  STOJ   | MARY | xxx     | …
------------------------------------
```

Query: **SELECT * FROM hirings WHERE employee_id = 469**

Result: **hirings (3r x 11)**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | Employee_id | WeekHour | Level_id | Contract_id | DeadlineType | DeadlineDate | PartTime | ChargeDate | DischargeDate | Contract |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 629|     469     |   36     |     9    |      3      |        4     | 2022-10-31   |    0     | 2022-05-09 | 2022-10-31    |  (NULL)  |
| 761|     469     |   36     |     2    |      2      |        1     | 2023-03-31   |    0     | 2022-11-01 | 2023-03-31    |  (NULL)  |
| 943|     469     |   36     |     2    |      2      |        1     | 2023-10-30   |    0     | 2023-04-01 | (NULL)        |  (NULL)  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*I want to emphasize that this issue doesn't appears on my PC with the same database imported for tests.
In other PC's this issue was appears about two month ago without any software modification.*

Comment: Can you provide example data for how it is wrong? i.e. some sample data, the result you are getting with your query, and the expected result?

Comment: Are you sure the result is wrong and not just a different arbitrary result? i.e. "If you select a non-grouped column or a value computed from a non-grouped column, it is undefined which row the returned value is taken from" https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by/

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you mean to be doing `SELECT MAX(id) as id, employee_id`, not `SELECT id, MAX(id), employee_id`.  The latter will return an arbitrary one of the id values for each employee_id (and generates an mt column named `MAX(id)` which you don't use).

Enabling the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode will prevent you from making mistakes like this.  This is the default in recent mysql.

Comment: I edited the query as you told me, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: @Stefano Can you post your edited query that was based on this answer? Looking at the additional details you've provided, I agree with ysth's answer here, so I'd like to understand exactly what you tried.

Comment: @EdmCoff: This is the edited query:
'WITH mt AS (SELECT MAX(id), id, employee_id FROM hirings group BY employee_id)
                   SELECT d.*, mt.employee_id, mt.id FROM mt
                   LEFT JOIN hirings a ON a.id = mt.id
                   LEFT JOIN employees d ON d.id = mt.employee_id
                   WHERE (dischargedate IS NULL OR dischargedate > CURDATE()-1) AND company_id = 1
                   GROUP BY d.id ORDER BY surname'

Comment: Thanks. You have reordered the max(id) and the id, but you haven't actually followed the suggestion to change it to `MAX(id) as id`. If you do this, it should eliminate the arbitrariness of your query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved replacing the old query with this:

```
SELECT * FROM employees d 
         WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM hirings a 
          WHERE a.employee_id = d.id 
          AND (a.dischargedate IS NULL OR a.dischargedate > CURDATE()-1) 
          AND company_id = 1)
          GROUP BY d.id ORDER BY surname
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).